# VO query not getting executing

Tags: oracle-adf

Following is the code in my AM implementation

```
public void edit(){`testVO().setWhereClause(null);
        testVO().setWhereClauseParams(null);
        testVO().applyViewCriteria(testVO().getViewCriteria("SearchCriteria"));
        testVO().setNamedWhereClauseParam("a",method.getContentOwnerId()); 
         testVO().setNamedWhereClauseParam("b",method.getTaxSrch()); 
         testVO().setNamedWhereClauseParam("c",method.getTaxRgmCodeSrch()); 
         testVO().setNamedWhereClauseParam("d",method.getTaxStatCodeSrch()); 
         testVO().setNamedWhereClauseParam("e",method.getTaxRateCodeSrch()); 
         testVO().setNamedWhereClauseParam("f",method.getRateTypeCode()); 
         testVO().setNamedWhereClauseParam("g",method.getTaxJurisCodeSrch());  
         testVO().executeQuery();}`
```

testVO() method returns the TestVO. Bind variables are being picked up (can tell from the log) but when the line

```
testVO().executeQuery()
```

is encountered, the query is not getting executed.

Any ideas why this might happen or how to debug this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see your VO executing when you open it from BC Tester?